# Помогите определить рекурентное соотношение и написать функцию на с++

Tags: c++

Вот такое задание:

> Определить закономерность формирования последовательности, записать
> рекуррентное соотношение для n-го члена последовательности.
> Реализовать рекурсивную функцию вычисления n-го члена
> последовательности. Вычислить 7-й член последовательности. Оценить
> сложность алгоритма.

Сама последовательность: 1,1,2,9,737

```
int sequence(long int n) {
    if (n == 1 || n == 2)
        return 1;
    return pow(sequence(n - 1), 3) + pow(sequence(n - 2), 3);
}
int main(){
   long int counter = 4;
 sequence(counter);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: a(n) = a(n-1)^3 + a(n-2)^3 - ну, а код напишите сами, писать такой простой код за вас - это уже прямое оскорбление неверием в ваши силы :) Только учтите, что 7-й член - 64151935432803278787493321, так что нужно немного длинной арифметики...

Comment: В чем сложность хотя бы начать решение задачи? Написать `main`, хотя бы какую-то реализацию и вывод. И наплести нам мол вы не можете понять как сделать. И мы бы поверили и помогли вам. Но вы просто в наглую условие скидываете.

Comment: простите что не уточнил, я написал код ,но в нем требуются правки,хотел бы понять какие

Comment: @ДаниилИщенко а в чем конкретно ошибка? Не правильный ответ выдает при каком то значении `n`, если да, то скорее всего происходит переполнение. Почитайте комментарий @Harry

Comment: @Павел Ериков Дело в том что вывода вообще не происходит, в main я обьявил переменную counter, записал в нее число, и потом вызвал функцию, аргументом которой был counter

Comment: @ДаниилИщенко выложите так же функцию `main` т.к. я сейчас проверил и у меня все работает правильно

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Выложил

Comment: Так вы ничего и не выводите хахах. `cout << sequence(counter);` напишите в `main`

Comment: Ахахахах,действительно,простите, это уже невнимательность)

Answer (score 2):

Хотя вопрос был написать на C++, но в цитате самого задания не говорится про язык, кроме того как оказывается 7-й элемент последовательности это 26-значное число `64151935432803278787493321`, для его вычисления C++ с его стандартной библиотекой не достаточно, т.к. нужна длинная арифметика, в наибольший 64-битный `uint64_t` тип число не влезет.

Поэтому предлагаю решение на языке [Python](https://python.org/), т.к. он имеет встроенную целочисленную длинную арифметику, извините за несоответствие запроса на C++.

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://tio.run/##VYsxDoAgFMV2TvFGftQBGEyM3kaILB9EjPH0qLhotzZpPPMS2JQyW4fNrpJpELjxDoxxgn71Idm8J4YSH4nhkHVDB0UtDKH5RV2jEDF5zrX2RKVc)

```
def seq(n):
    if n <= 2:
        return 1
    return pow(seq(n - 1), 3) + pow(seq(n - 2), 3)

print(seq(7))
```

Вывод:

```
64151935432803278787493321
```